# Rails 5: collection_check_boxes from enum (hash)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, form-for

How to create collection_check_boxes from hashed `enum`:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :roles, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles, allow_destroy: true
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  enum permission: {
    read_contact: 0,
    write_contact: 1,
    read_message: 2,
    write_message: 3
  }
end
```

I tried in many ways:

```
= form_for(@user) do |f|
  = f.collection_check_boxes :permissions, Role.permissions, :last, :first
  = f.submit class: "button"
```

I got `undefined method permissions for #<User:0x00007...>`

If I try with:

```
= form_for(@user) do |f|
  = f.collection_check_boxes :roles, Role.permissions, :last, :first
  = f.submit class: "button"
```

User controller:

```
def update
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save 
     ...
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:roles)
end
```

I got `Unpermitted parameter: :roles`

Despite of looking at params:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "user"=>{"roles"=>["", "1", "2"]}, "commit"=>"Update", "id"=>"3"}
```

Also this is check to create, how to uncheck to delete?

**Update:** Try as @Steve said I should use a nested form

```
= form_for(@user) do |f|
  = f.fields_for :roles do |ff|
    = ff.collection_check_boxes :permission, Role.permissions, :first, :first
  = f.submit class: "button"
```

I got a correct checked permission from database! Yay!!

However on sending form, this is params:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "user"=>{"roles_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"permission"=>["", "read_message", "write_message"], "id"=>"18"}}}, "commit"=>"Update", "id"=>"3"}
```

I got `Unpermitted parameter: :permission` though I have permit it in controller:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(roles_attributes: %i[id permission _destroy])
end
```

I think the params should be like this:

```
params = { user: {
  roles_attributes: [
    { permission: 'read_message' },
    { permission: 'write_message' },
    ...
  ]
}}
```

Instead, what I got in params now:

```
params = { user: {
  roles_attributes: [
    { permission: ['', 'read_message', 'write_message' }
    ...
  ]
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Strong Parameters, you need to tell Rails when you're expecting an array of scalar values; otherwise, it expects just a single value.

The syntax you need here is:

```
params.require(:user).permit(roles: [])
```

If you need to have specific keys in your `roles` array in future, you could also do:

```
params.require(:user).permit(roles: {:role_id, :name})
```

This would allow any number of roles, but each role would only be allowed to have the keys `role_id` and `name`.

Hope this helps; I struggled with this recently myself.

Comment: I passed the Unpermitted parameter thanks to your suggestion. However, I got error when save: `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch - UserRole(#70216659953380) expected, got "0" which is an instance of String(#70216944287200):`

Comment: I _think_ the problem here is that you're trying to pass a permission instead of a Role. For nested attributes, you'd typically have a sub form: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

Comment: also @Steve:  `(roles: {:role_id, :name})` should be array `[]`, I tested with {} and not work

Comment: I have update post and used `nested-forms` as you suggest! @Steve Hill

Answer (score 0):

And with the undefined method error, try putting the enum decleration inside a method.

```
def permissions
    enum permission: {
       read_contact: 0,
       write_contact: 1,
       read_message: 2,
       write_message: 3
    }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna nested form. You can try this.

In an HTML file

```
- Role.permissions.each do |key, value|
  = f.fields_for :roles, @user.roles.build do |fr|
    = fr.checkbox :permission, {}, value, false
```

In the model file: user.rb

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles, reject_if:  proc { |attributes| attributes['permission'].blank? }
```

The correct params
`roles_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"permission"=>"1"}, "3"=>{"permission"=>"2"}}`

Answer (score 0):

if you use `fields_for` with nested_attribures . In form with `fields_for` you have to use `f.check_box` to make this form can render html with attribute that can make params as you expect

```
params = { user: {
  roles_attributes: [
    { permission: 'read_message' },
    { permission: 'write_message' },
    ...
  ]
}}
```

If you using `ff.collection_check_boxes :permission, Role.permissions, :first, :first` all checked value will be set into field `permission` so that params will be `permission: ['', 'read_message', 'write_message']`

You can see in doc of collection_check_boxes https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes